# Evolution 3.2 non standard SMTP port

Tags: evolution

I've just been forced to update my lovely, stable Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 and the process has been dreadful tbh. "improvements" to Evolution have pretty much broken it for me. My biggest gripe is that I cannot set a non-standard port for SMTP. My provider listens on 2525 for mail (not 25,465 or 587).

On the older Evolution I could just append the port to the mail host eg: host.mail.somewhere:2525 but that does not work in 3.2. It borks the hostname and STB with "Could not connect to mailhost%25252525253a2525:"

I'm really disappointed in this and think I already know that I'm going to have to switch to Thunderbird (which I really don't like) - but just in case, does anyone know a workaround for this really irritating 'feature' ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just enter the port number in the port number input rather than the server box. Make sure you close Evolution after entering the new port number and restart it to take effect.

[image]